# Secure LDAP Auth?

Tags: web-services, authentication, ldap

I would like to auth my users on an Active Directory server to access a webserver. However I don't want the passwords to be sent in clear to the webserver.

All the solutions I have found use a POST request with the plain password such as this example:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

Is there a way to hash the password on the client side then send a token to the backend which is used to authenticate to the LDAP server?

PHP is just an example, my question is not language specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the hashing algorithm of the LDAP-backend then you might be able to hash the password in javascript and send only that to the server. That would mean though that your LDAp-authentication script needs to be able to read all the password-hashes to be able to compare them to the prehashed password.

I'd consider that a higher risk than sending the cleartext-password via a TLS-secured HTTP-connection (aka Https) to the server that then uses the default bind-mechanism also via a tls-secured (ldaps or starttls).

And as you are not using the bind-mechanism all possible enforcements of password-policies or locked passwords that are readily available and implemented and supported by your direcrory-admins now need to be rebuilt and maintained by yourself  also.